# Can we program Nxt2 in C++ under Visual studio 2010?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, programming

I'd like to know if it is possible to develop C++ software for NXT2 using Visual Studio 2010 as IDE. I know there are small online projects for NXT but I can't find nothing about NXT2.... Any suggestions would be more than welcomed
about libraries, software and firmware that is required to achieve this goal: C++ and Visual Studio for NXT2.

Comment: There is no practical difference between the bricks in the NXT 1.0 and NXT 2.0 sets.

Comment: This should be on Stack Overflow, or something.

Comment: @muntoo Happy to get your take on this on [meta - Are questions about programming NXT on-topic?](http://meta.bricks.stackexchange.com/q/132/56)

Answer (score 7):

I think that all you might need is the [Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/robotics). The examples that I could find all refer to C#, VB.Net, or the included VPL languages but there isn't any reason you wouldn't be able to reference the same objects from managed C++.

It does look like there might not be a full set of services for all of the more recent parts judging from some of the [comments in one of the examples that I saw](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Microsoft-Robotics-Studio-and-Lego-Mindstorms-NXT), but the author of that article does have a few other notes [elsewhere](http://www.brianpeek.com/category/LegoNXT.aspx).

After installing and playing around with it a bit myself, I did find a link to the [MSDN documentation for using NXT with MRDS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb483027.aspx) that you can look through before you get started. (I wasn't able to give much of it a try yet because I'm out of batteries with my NXT brick.)

Beyond that a [Google search for "mrds nxt"](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mrds%20nxt) found the following likely useful items:

- [CodeProject example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/LegoMindstorms2MRDS.aspx) (C#) with a link to a [previous article](http://blogs.gokulnath.com//2010/09/04/MicrosoftRoboticsServiceForLEGONXT20.aspx) on the same site.
- An [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb870550.aspx).
- A whole slew of [examples on CodePlex](http://mrdssamples.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

There are some answers to this on Stack Overflow: [C++ OOP Library for Programming the Lego NXT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926078/c-oop-library-for-programming-the-lego-nxt/14676215)

NXT++ is the best choice with dual USB/Bluetooth support. 
The C++ communication library has more features, but it's Bluetooth-only.